# SQL query to fetch previous record using previous id column

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I am trying to write a SQL query where I can query the latest and previous/last two comments. I have table structures as below -

***Record Table***

| Id | RecordName | LatestCommentId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Record 1 | 3 |
| 2 | Record 2 | 6 |
| 3 | Record 3 | 7 |

***Comment Table***

| Id | Comment | PreviousCommentId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Comment 1 | NULL |
| 2 | Comment 2 | 1 |
| 3 | Comment 3 | 2 |
| 4 | Comment A | NULL |
| 5 | Comment B | 4 |
| 6 | Comment C | 5 |
| 7 | Comment P | NULL |

Record table references Comments table to get the latest comment id for that record. I want to create a query where I get the latest as well as previous comments like -

| RecordName | LatestComment | PreviousComment | PreviousComment1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Record 1 | Comment 3 | Comment 2 | Comment 1 |
| Record 2 | Comment C | Comment B | Comment A |
| Record 3 | Comment P | NULL | NULL |

I will be storing only last two comments along with latest comment.

I was also exploring the Recursive CTE option and here is what I was able to create -

```
WITH COMMENTS_HISTORY AS (
  SELECT
    Id,
    CommentBody,
    PreviousCommentId
  FROM 
    Comment
  WHERE 
    PreviousCommentId IS NULL
 
  UNION ALL
   
  SELECT
    c.Id,
    c.CommentBody,
    c.PreviousCommentId
  FROM 
    Comment c, COMMENTS_HISTORY ch
  WHERE c.PreviousCommentId = ch.Id
)
SELECT
    c.Id,
    c.CommentBody AS 'Latest Comment',
    ch.CommentBody AS 'Comment 1'
FROM 
    COMMENTS_HISTORY ch
LEFT JOIN 
    Comment c
ON
    ch.PreviousCommentId = c.Id
```

Comment: @DaleK - I tried to explore Recursive CTE option but failed to achieve the result. So thought of taking help from community.

Comment: @DaleK I have added what I was trying. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to join the `comment` table 3 times, one per comment column

```
SELECT
    r.recordname,
    c.comment AS LatestComment,
    pc.comment AS PreviousComment,
    pc1.comment AS PreviousComment1
FROM record r
LEFT JOIN comment c ON c.id = r.latestcommentid
LEFT JOIN comment pc ON pc.id = c.previouscommentid
LEFT JOIN comment pc1 ON pc1.id = pc.previouscommentid
```

Output

| recordname | LatestComment | PreviousComment | PreviousComment1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Record 1 | Comment 3 | Comment 2 | Comment 1 |
| Record 2 | Comment C | Comment B | Comment A |
| Record 3 | Comment P | *null* | *null* |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4e4fe567f5256f61018b100845a454c1)*